# Pandas iloc not returning data slice

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a CSV file containing stock data of 1500+ companies. The first column contains dates and subsequent columns contain company data.

When I use the **iloc** feature to split the CSV file into smaller files containing lesser columns, it's generating an even bigger file.

Following is what the data looks like.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

csv_path = "new-data.csv"
filename = 1
out_path = "C:\\Users\\ThirdHandBD\\Desktop\\Data Splitting\\pd-split\\" + str(filename) + ".csv"

#column increment
x = 30 * 59

'''for index, row in df.itertuples():
    if index == ((x * filename) + 1):
        pd.read_csv(csv_path).iloc[:, :index].to_csv(out_path)
        filename += 1'''

pd.read_csv(csv_path, skiprows = 1, dtype='unicode').iloc[:, :1].to_csv(out_path)
```

**New file is bigger than original.**

[image]

No errors thrown, dtype set to unicode to get around the low memory error. The file size is about 300 MB and similar dtypes have worked for others with similar file sizes. Skiprows set to 1 because the first row is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

[image]

The is what the new data looks like. It adds a bunch of commas then the rest of the data is same. How do I fix this?

**EDIT x 2:**

After taking mightpile's suggestion into consideration, I get rid of everything except for the headers on row 6 and cut down on rows using a text editor. Then I run the following code.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_path = "C:\\Users\\ThirdHandBD\\Desktop\\Data Splitting\\pd-split\\small-data.csv"
out_path = "C:\\Users\\ThirdHandBD\\Desktop\\Data Splitting\\pd-split\\1.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header=0, dtype='unicode')
print("I read in a dataframe with {} columns and {} rows.".format(
len(df.columns), len(df)
))

out_df = df.iloc[:, :1]
out_df.to_csv(out_path)
# This should be the same as df, but with only the first column.
# Check it with similar code to above.
```

**RESULT**

I read in a dataframe with 1546 columns and 13 rows.

[image]

It only cuts a random number of column headers. When I ran mightypile's code of first and last column, I got random headers returned. My csv is not being read right and I don't understand why.

```
print("The first and last columns are:")
print(df.head(1))
print(df.tail(1))
```

**TERMINAL OUT:**

[image]

The same terminal output repeats on and on. Sorry for being a dumb human but I feel like I'm going backward instead of making progress.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the data. Perhaps your two-digit floats are being converted to 64-bit floats, then converted back to text but with 20 or so digits in the decimal place. There's an extra 16 bytes per row in your csv file.

Comment: When I load into Excel, the columns and rows it can load are exactly the same. Shouldn't I be seeing only the first column?

Comment: If you use a text editor to view the raw data, you ought to be able to see the differences between the files. Excel is interpreting your data, then displaying it. It's tough to tell whether Excel is showing you two digits of precision because it's a text field, or because it has cell properties set, or what. A text editor will show you the raw text.

Comment: Or you could read_csv into a pd.DataFrame variable, print(df.head()), and see what it's reading before you write it back out again.

Comment: Added new screenshot. It adds a bunch of commas, then the rest of the data is same.

Comment: Try specifying a semicolon as your separator with sep=";" as an argument to read_csv. It looks like it's probably semicolon-separated rather than comma-separated.

Comment: That worked, thank you, I can breathe a little now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems. Your input csv has entirely different formatting from lines 0-5 than it does from 6-on. The first 6 rows are not structured like a DataFrame with rows and columns. If you need these data, you might need to write some custom code to extract them.

A second suggestion would be to use a text editor (google for suggestions, but these are NOT Word, Excel, or Writepad) to save a smaller portion of your data to experiment with. Trying to figure out how to read csv files with a 300MB monster is going to cause you a lot of pain and wasted time.

From 6-on, you have what appears from your partial images to be more DataFrame-like, with column headers on row 6 and data beyond that. But it's impossible to tell how many columns are there from your image. So, first, ignore the more complex structures at the top of the file, and see if you can figure out what you are reading from the rest of one file, and whether you are writing what you think you are. Once you dial in your approach on a single file, you can start iterating over more.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_path = "new-data.csv"
out_path = "C:\\Users\\ThirdHandBD\\Desktop\\Data Splitting\\pd-split\\1.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header=6, dtype='unicode')
print("I read in a dataframe with {} columns and {} rows.".format(
    len(df), len(df.columns)
))
print("The first 4 and last 4 columns are:")
print(df.head(4))
print(df.tail(4))

out_df = df.iloc[:, :1]
# This should be the same as df, but with only the first column.
# Check it with similar code to above.
```

If your rows are still too large to visualize with the .head() and .tail() functions, I would again urge you to start with a "toy" dataset so you can get an intuition for what the code is doing for you. That's tough and frustrating with large data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get a text editor and cut to retry creating a custom code. This dataset has been causing a lot of pain for the past few weeks.

Comment: Notepad++ is a nice, powerful, raw text editor for Windows that's free. Many great options out there, but Notepad++ will get you started.

Comment: Updated the question, the headers are being read all wrong and no clue why.

Comment: You can also print individual cells with print(df.iloc[0, 0]) and other values for 0. That can tell you if a single cell holds a single value, or way more than you had anticipated. You may have thousands of semicolons in a single cell if read_csv is waiting for the next comma to split the string.